# Cannot delete fields in a myphpadmin mysql table (on awardspace free hosting)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using a free version of phpmyadmin on awardspace and find that I cannot - as per the usual on shared hosting - delete or edit fields in a table - see below screenshot.

[image]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: As you can read in the message, as you don't have a unique column, the edit, delete functions are not available. You must have a Unique column for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was. I simply needed to edit the database and ensure there was a primary key. As the table had been created and had data I had to delete that whole field with existing data and re-create it.
I created it with AI (Auto-increment) and as primary key.
This brought back the EDIT/DELETE functons.